How to get an extract of users in Server Manager RDS Collections
I can see a list of connections in server manager > Remote Desktop Services > Collections but I cannot see a way of extracting that list of users to CSV. Is there a way of doing that?
I have tried to look for a button to extract and cannot see one and I have looked at Powershell but seems quite complicated. Is there an easy way of getting it extracted?

You could use the Get-RemoteSessions function I have posted here
